# Verify a X.509 certificate with Java ME and Bouncy Castle

Tags: java-me, x509certificate, bouncycastle

Can anybody point me to an example of verifying a X.509 certificate with Bouncy Castle under Java ME?
I can see how to easily do this in Java SE code with java.security.cert.Certificate.verify(), but I could not find an equivalent method in the lightweight BC API.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers
Dino

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `com.sun.midp.ssl.X509Certificate` instead.